# Adding stock loses to taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, capital-loss

In USA there is normally about 12k deduction for a single person filling taxes. If I have 1k losses in stocks can I take the 12k default deduction + 1k? I know there is a 3k limit to stock losses but I am not sure if I can combine the default 12k and the stock loss.

I think I have 2 options:

1. Take the 12k deduction
2. Have losses over 12k (not stocks) then I can add 1k stock loss.

Could someone explain?

Comment: To be clear: net capital loss is limited to 3k _per year_, but can be carried forward as long as needed (until you have offsetting gains, or use it up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Losses are not part of itemized deductions. You can take the stock losses regardless of whether you itemize.

Comment: What are these non itemize losses called? I am wondering what else falls in this category.

Comment: Well, on the 1040, it’s line 6, capital gain or loss.

Comment: Net capital gains/losses are part of your gross income (called “total income” on form 1040). Other things included in total income besides wages are interest, dividends, pensions, social security benefits, rental income, business income, alimony, and unemployment compensation.

Comment: Alimony only for settlements made in 2018 or earlier, and not if modified to apply TCJA. Plus many other things like some scholarships and fellowships, gambling winnings, cancellation of debt, recoveries of previous loss or deduction items, jury pay, lawsuit damages or settlements other than physical injury, and the ever popular 'illegal activities' -- remember that's how they got Capone!